# Regex index 0 how it exactly works

Tags: java, regex, string

By compiling the following:

```
 System.out.println(Pattern.matches(".?(\\d)$","3"));
```

It returns true because before `3` there is nothing and `?` check for a one or zero.
However 3 is already the first character of the input which starts at 0 and end at 1. How can the jvm recognize that there is nothing before 3.
For example the following.

System.out.println(Pattern.matches(".*","hello");

It returns true as well but only the very last character gets matched with "nothing".
There should not be a "nothing" character at the beginning of a string, only at the end of it right?

Comment: Your question is a little unclear, but could it be you are looking for the `^` start-of-string anchor (`^.?(\\d)$`)?

Comment: @Tomalak no I would like to know why ".?(\\d)$" matches "3". .? in that case should match anything with a preceding character. Since "3" does not have any preceding character. How can the jvm find out that there is nothing before if the first character is "3".

Comment: Because `.?` means "zero or one", so it happily matches zero characters.

Comment: @Tomalak yep.. but how it find out that there are 0 characters? what kind of control makes? For example the last character is alwasys "", it is not true for the very first one though.

Comment: You are lacking basic understanding of the way regexes work and should [read about them](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) first. For the moment, just assume that it can find out and that an optional character that's *not* there is a positive match as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This is not really about the JVM.  This is about Java regular expressions.
2. The regular expression ".*" means "match 0 or more characters".  It's easy to satisfy this, since a blank string has 0 characters, and therefore satisfies this.  Whether Java regular expressions will choose to be lazy and match an empty string, or to be greedy and match the entire string depends on the implementation of Java regular expressions.  If you read this excellent writeup (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) <strike>you can see that patterns like ".*" in Java are considered "reluctant" quantifiers and will prefer to take as little as possible</strike>.
3. <strike>Based on the information in that writeup, you can see that a pattern like ".{0,}" is a greedy version of the same expression.  Perhaps you'd like to use that instead if this is truly a problem for you.</strike>

Comment: Accordingly to the link you posted in your answer .* is greedy and .*? is reluctant.

Comment: Thanks @Rollerball, you're right.  I can confirm that ".*" is in fact greedy and will match the whole string.  My mistake.  Did you by any chance invoke the ".find()" function of the match more than once?

Answer (score 1):

You are not interpreting your regex correctly. There is no such thing as a "nothing character" . Rather, your pattern reads: any charachter followed by a digit at the end of the string **OR** a digit at the end of the string.

And surely, "3" fits the second description very well.

Comment: i guess his nothing character is `$`

Answer (score 0):

`matches` method tries to match the input exactly.

so there's no need to use `^`,`$`..